# Setting the 'Host' header on Sinch callback events

Tags: sinch, sinch-verification

I'm using Sinch's verification service for verifying phone numbers, and I'm wondering if there is any way to set the `Host` header for incoming callback events (from Sinch to my backend service) such as "verification request events" and "verification result events".

My situation is the following: the service that responds to these events is sitting behind a reverse proxy. The only way this service can receive external HTTP requests is if those requests specify the virtual host's name using the `Host` HTTP header.

I couldn't find any way of doing this in the documentation. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: No, thats not possible

Comment: Would it be in any way possible to make this a configurable setting? Maybe inside of the developer dashboard? I can imagine that a lot of people would need this feature especially if they are behind an API gateway or proxy, and it's not a very hard thing to implement.

Comment: (assuming you work for sinch or are in contact with the devs)